# search bar in disappears while inserting search text in ios

Tags: ios, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I am using searchDisplayController and ios7 . everything is working fine but while i am entering search text in search bar ,search bar is disappears from the view but i am still able to type the search text and search.any idea what's going wrong.

Comment: Are you using autolayouts? Please post some code.

Comment: thanks for quick reply. yes i am using storyboard.Now i am able to solve it.it is because of xcode 6. In xcode 6 extended edges under the top bar is selected by default , need to uncheck it.